# How to access DB in private subnet

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, private-subnet

How to acccess the Cloud SQL?

Assume that i have a db in a private subnet, i am able to access the private subnet but not the cloud SQL inside the private subnet using bastion host.

Comment: Can you check if they are on the same VPC?

Comment: they are in the same VPC

Comment: And you are sure you enabled Private IP on the Cloud SQL Instance? Else you will have to use the Cloud SQL Proxy to access it.